# 配列を使った少し複雑なグルーピング方法について

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQLで不完全リスト情報に基づく完全リスト作成をしたいのですが、良い方法はないでしょうか。
次のテーブルがあります。

```
CREATE TABLE abscissa (
  a_id TEXT
  o_id_list TEXT[]
);

CREATE TABLE ordinate (
  o_id TEXT
  a_id_list TEXT[]
);
```

a_id_list, o_id_list は それぞれ a_id, o_id の不完全リストとなっています。
これをもとに、完全リストを作りたいのです。
具体例でいうと、次のようなデータがあるとします。

```
a_1  | {o_1, o_2, o_4}
a_2  | {o_1, o_3, o_5}
a_3  | {o_3, o_5}

o_1  | {a_1, a_2}
o_2  | {a_1}
o_3  | {a_2, a_3}
o_4  | {a_1}
o_5  | {a_2, a_3}
```

これを

```
{a_1, a_2, a_3} | {o_1, o_2, o_3, o_4, o_5}
```

という形にまとめたいのです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

追記：

重なりがない場合というのは、

```
a_4 | {o_6,o_7}
a_5 | {o_8,o_9}
```

というような場合です。

使い方に慣れておらず、要領が悪くてすみません。

Comment: 書式修正していただきありがとうございました。

Comment: だいぶ前の質問なので解決済みかもしれませんが・・・「重なりがないレコード」がある場合の例を挙げていただけませんか？

Comment: 返信がすっかり遅くなってしまいました。　重なりがない場合というのは、a_4 | {o_6}  a_4 | {o_7}  という場合です。

Comment: すみません、コメント欄では目立ちにくく改行等も使えないので、質問下にある編集リンクから質問文に追記していただけませんか？現在質問文に書かれている例のように、変形後の形も書かれているとわかりやすいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

「グラフの各連結成分の要素を列挙する」問題のように思えます

グラフの問題はSQLを使わず、手続き的に探索した方が簡単で分かりやすいと思います
効率の良いアルゴリズム(深さ優先探索など)も多く知られています

SQLを書いてみましたが、再帰SQLを使った複雑なものになってしまっています
共通部分を持つ配列を変化がなくなるまで追加することで、極大なグラフを得ています

```
CREATE TABLE foo(foo_id int4, bar_id_list int4[]);
INSERT INTO foo(foo_id, bar_id_list)
VALUES
(1, ARRAY[1, 2, 4]),
(2, ARRAY[1, 3, 5]),
(3, ARRAY[3, 5]),
(4, ARRAY[6]),
(5, ARRAY[7, 8]),
(6, ARRAY[8, 9]),
(7, ARRAY[9, 10]),
(8, ARRAY[10, 11]);

WITH RECURSIVE r AS (
  SELECT
    T1.foo_id,
    T1.bar_id_list
  FROM
    foo T1

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    T1.foo_id,
    array_agg(DISTINCT T1.bar_id ORDER BY T1.bar_id) AS bar_id_list
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
      T1.foo_id,
      unnest(T1.bar_id_list || T2.bar_id_list) AS bar_id,
      T2.bar_id_list AS prev_bar_id_list
    FROM
      foo T1
    CROSS JOIN
      r T2
    WHERE
      T1.bar_id_list && T2.bar_id_list
  ) T1
  GROUP BY
    foo_id
  HAVING
    max(T1.prev_bar_id_list) <> array_agg(T1.bar_id ORDER BY T1.bar_id)
)
SELECT
  T1.foo_id,
  T1.bar_id_list
FROM (
  SELECT
    T1.foo_id,
    T1.bar_id_list,
    row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY T1.foo_id ORDER BY array_length(T1.bar_id_list, 1) DESC) AS row_number
  FROM
    r T1
) T1
WHERE T1.row_number = 1;
```

---

```
 foo_id |  bar_id_list  
--------+---------------
      1 | {1,2,3,4,5}
      2 | {1,2,3,4,5}
      3 | {1,2,3,4,5}
      4 | {6}
      5 | {7,8,9,10,11}
      6 | {7,8,9,10,11}
      7 | {7,8,9,10,11}
      8 | {7,8,9,10,11}
(8 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
with w1 as (select array_agg(a_id order by a_id) from (select distinct unnest(a_id_list) as a_id from ordinate) as t2)
, w2 as (select array_agg(o_id order by o_id) from (select distinct unnest(o_id_list) as o_id from abscissa) as t1)
select * from w1,w2
```

Comment: ご回答いただき、ありがとうございます。
試してみたのですが、意図と違う結果になってしまいました。
つまり、いただいたSQLでは全データが一つにまとまってしまいました。

説明が悪かったと思うのですが、やりたかったことは、１つでも重なりのあるレコードを相互に連結し、重なりが一つもないレコードは連結しない、というものです。
上の説明では、重なりがないレコードを書かなかったので、わかりにくかったと思います。失礼しました。